# Gallery widget rebind issue

Tags: android

I am working in an android application. I am using a Gallery widget that I am binding a Imageview and an Imagebutton to that. On the button click I hide one of the buttons in the gallery, but after scrolling and coming back that hidden button becomes again visible. What causes this to happen. Does the gallery bind again  after scroll. Please provide any valid link if possible to solve this problem.

This is my code:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private int mGalleryItemBackground;
    private Activity mContext;
    private Integer[] Images;




    public ImageAdapter(Activity c,Integer[] images) {
        this.mContext = c;
        this.Images=images;
        TypedArray attr = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.HelloGal999lery);
        mGalleryItemBackground = attr.getResourceId(
                R.styleable.HelloGal999lery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        attr.recycle();

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return Images.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 1;
    }

    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent __e) {
        return false;
    }


   public  static class ViewHolder{
        public ImageView imageView1;
        public ImageButton btn1;
        public ProgressBar processdialog;
     }
        //Binding image and button to gallery
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  

         final ViewHolder holder;   
         View rowView = convertView;

        if(rowView==null)
        {
         LayoutInflater inflater = mContext.getLayoutInflater();
         rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null, true);
         holder=new ViewHolder();
         holder.imageView1=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ImageViewuser);    
         holder.btn1=(ImageButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.Download);
         holder.processdialog=(ProgressBar)rowView.findViewById(R.id.progressbar_Horizontal);
         holder.imageView1.setImageResource(Images[position]);               
         holder.imageView1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
         holder.imageView1.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);      
         holder.btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                              
                //Toast.makeText(mContext, position+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                    
                holder.processdialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   
                BackgroundAsyncTask dd=new BackgroundAsyncTask();
                dd.execute();
            }
             class BackgroundAsyncTask extends
                AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

              int myProgress;

              @Override
              protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               Toast.makeText(mContext,
                     "Download finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             holder.processdialog.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             holder.btn1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              }

              @Override
              protected void onPreExecute() {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             /*  Toast.makeText(mContext,
                     "Downloading", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               myProgress = 0;*/
                  holder.processdialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  holder.btn1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              }

              @Override
              protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               while(myProgress<100){
                myProgress++;
                publishProgress(myProgress);
                   SystemClock.sleep(100);
                   holder.btn1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                   holder.processdialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               }
               return null;
              }

              @Override
              protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

                  holder.processdialog.setProgress(values[0]);
              }
             }
        });

        }

         return rowView;                    
    }
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

it maybe the view is reused.
try to delete if(rowView==null) .

Comment: I am not getting the result even if I delete the code. Please help me.